# How do you set the body to the full size of the screen in html and css?

Tags: html, css

The body in my code is a little off of the left and top of the screen, I tried removing `content-box` and removing margin, but it isn't working. I also tried absolutely positioning it `left:0;` and `top:0;` but none of that works, here is my code;

```css
body {
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind. I fixed this by simply changing `margin:none;`, to `margin:0;`.

Answer (score 0):

In `CSS` make `height` and `width` 100% .

Comment: Didn't work for me.